# Adding geometry to rows with missing X,Y inArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geometry, editing, xy

I have a table with X, Y data that contains many rows with still missing coordinates. Now I would like to edit it in ArcGIS 10 and simply add the geometry for selected lines after identifying the correct location on a base map.

This seems so simple and basic, but I can't get it to work. Always, adding a point in ArcGIS will just create a new row. With more than 1000 yet unidentified spots, this is really cumbersome.

Comment: I assume you have a point geometry? You are right, clicking again (in edit session) will only create new features. Your features with "missing" coordinates, are only missing to you. Arcmap probably interprets that as 0,0, which means that you'll have to **move** those, already displayed, points to the correct location. Right-click and then Zoom to Layer will show you the full extent of your feature class, and can probably help narrow down where those points are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Moving features from 0,0 to the correct location may be tedious depending on how many you have to move and also may lead to additional user error.  I would suggest doing this:

1. Select and export a standalone geodatabase table for all the features that are at 0,0.
2. Start an edit session on the table and put in the correct x/y coordinates.
3. After you are done filling out this table, Make a XY event layer of it and export it out as a new feature class.
4. Finally, delete the 0,0 points out of the original feature class then merge the original feature and the fixed feature class together.